# can't update anything in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

Anything that i change does not reflect when i run it. i don't know what happened it just sort of happened. i can't find anything on the internet except one where it says to build the solution which i already did and it was successful but it did not solve my problem. I tried editing the text putting a lot of buttons. I can see them getting added in the designer but nothing is reflecting when i run it or click the play button. Please help me. Thanks in advance.
I am using visual studio 2013

Comment: What kind of project are you running? WPF ... Console ... Winforms .. ?

Comment: Winforms sir mungflesh

Comment: Are you building in release mode and debugging without rebuilding the debug code. If not, check where the code is building to.

Comment: That suggests the form you are editing at design time, is not the one you are running at run time. PS if you use rebuild solution to solve a problem do clean solution first.

Comment: @AndrewJansen i am building in debug mode.. the code is building to the bin\Debug of my project

Answer (score 1):

If its a web project, Clean the Temporary Files stored in framework folder,

**%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework**

If its Desktop App, Delete the Debug Folder, both in **bin** & **obj** folders

Comment: it is not a web project. after deleting what would i do?

Comment: Re-Build the complete solution

Comment: Yes whatever the output folder is for the binaries, manually delete those binaries